# AVPlayer exitFullScreen

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui

I've a problem with SwiftUI and AVPlayer. When i rotate the device in landscape mode, the player go in fullscreen mode, but when I rotate in portrait it not exit.
The struct for AVPlayer:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct AVPlayerControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var showFullScreen: Bool
    @Binding var player: AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AVPlayerControllerRepresentable>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        print("makeUIViewController->",showFullScreen)
        let controller  = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false;
        chooseScreenType(controller)
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_  uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController , context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AVPlayerControllerRepresentable>) {
        print("updateUIViewController->",showFullScreen)
        chooseScreenType(uiViewController)
    }
    
    private func chooseScreenType(_ controller: AVPlayerViewController) {
        print("chooseScreenType", self.showFullScreen)
        self.showFullScreen ? controller.enterFullScreen(animated: true) : controller.exitFullScreen(animated: true)
    }
    
}

extension AVPlayerViewController {
    func enterFullScreen(animated: Bool) {
        print("Enter full screen")
        perform(NSSelectorFromString("enterFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"), with: animated, with: nil)
    }
    
    func exitFullScreen(animated: Bool) {
        print("Exit full screen")
        perform(NSSelectorFromString("exitFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"), with: animated, with: nil)
    }
}
```

And this is my View:

```
 VStack{
                       

         AVPlayerControllerRepresentable(showFullScreen: $fullScreen, player: $player)
                                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                                    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            print("change rotation->",UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue)
                                            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
                                                print("landscape")
                                                self.fullScreen = true
                                            } else {
                                                print("portrait")
                                                self.fullScreen = false
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: 290, height: 220)
                                    .overlay {
                                       BoxTv()
                                    }
                                    .opacity(1.0)
                                    .padding([.bottom, .top], 40)
                            }.onAppear(){
                                self.player.play();
    }
```

Can anyone help me?
When rotate device in portrait mode, the function 'exitFullScreen' not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI seems get lost connection with representable in this scenario... anyway it is better UIKit things to be handled within UIKit flow. Representable concept has Coordinator for such cases.

So a possible approach to fix is to move everything inside `AVPlayerControllerRepresentable`.

[image]

Here is main part (tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5):

```
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AVPlayerControllerRepresentable>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller  = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false;

        context.coordinator.playerController = controller
        return controller
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
        weak var playerController: AVPlayerViewController? {
            didSet {
                playerController?.delegate = self
            }
        }

        private var subscriber: AnyCancellable? = nil
        override init() {
            super.init()
            subscriber = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
                .sink { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.rotated()
                }
        }

        func rotated() {
            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
                self.enterFullScreen(animated: true)
            } else {
                self.exitFullScreen(animated: true)
            }
        }

    //...
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestAVPlayerControllerFullScreen.swift)

Comment: nice solution thanks!
but I have a issue with performance on few iPhone simulators with iOS 15 - iPhone 13 Pro Max, iPhone 8 Plus, also on real device iPhone 7 Plus and just on simulator iPod touch 7th generation - performance is the expected behavior, means, on each rotation to landscape - Enter full screen is really video on full screen, for all others video don't expanded to full screen!? see attached for explained my words. Can you can make some notes? Thanks in advance.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wzvU.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wzvU.jpg)

Comment: Hello, it is working fine for the first time when rotating from Portrait to Landscape. But once you are back to portrait and try again, it doesn't work. Any help please?

Comment: @HemantSharma I had that issue too. You can fix it if you do the animations (enterFullScreen and exitFullScreen) within DispatchQueue.main.async { }